# Sending email on minimum qty in odoo8

Tags: python, email, odoo, odoo-8

hi i want to send an email in case the balance on a product is less than the minimum set in the custom module; i tried this code and i got an internal server error,any help plz, im new to odoo

```
class stock_minimum(models.Model):
        _name = "rcs.stock_minimum"

        warehouse = fields.Many2one("stock.warehouse")
        product = fields.Many2one("product.product")
        available = fields.Float(compute="_compute_balance", string="Available Quantity")
        percentage = fields.Float(compute="_compute_balance", string="Percentage %")
        quantity = fields.Float(string="Minimum Quantity")

        @api.one
        def _compute_balance(self):
                transactions = self.env['rcs.stock_transaction'].search([('product','=',self.product.id),('warehouse','=',self.warehouse.id)])
                balance = 0.0
                for transaction in transactions:
                        if transaction.trans_type == "incoming":
                                balance = balance + transaction.quantity
                        else:
                                balance = balance - transaction.quantity
                self.available = balance
                self.percentage = self.available / self.quantity * 100
#check from here the additional codes
       if (self.available <= quantity):
                    def send_mail(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None, template="minimumstock"):                                                                                                
                      for object in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                            template_id = self.pool.get('email.template').search(cr, uid, [("name","=",template)])                                                                           
                            mail_message = self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(cr,uid,template_id[0],object.id)
```

Comment: please edit the question adding the whole exception trace

Comment: and also please fix the indentation

Comment: let me try to get the trace

Comment: although i dont think its an indentation problem im fixing it too

Comment: i edited the indentation but still

Comment: i meant you need to fix the indentation of the code you provided here. It just doesn't seem right...

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo can u be more specific on indentation or exception trace

Comment: of course i am talking about indentation: you did not provide the trace. about indentation, seems like you are defining the send_mail method depending on a condition outside the _compute_balance method! fix the indentation.

Comment: well like this it stopped showing the error but it doesnt send

Comment: look, you seem to not understand. I am asking you to edit your question because I am not able to see what code you are running. But I somehow suppose it doesn't work just because you are defining send_mail without actually calling it!

Comment: see the edits on top,how im i supposed to do so

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo plus i edited the quantity to stock_minimum.quantity

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo any help on how to correct it or can u share a corrected syntax

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo i mean corrected code

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo let me try this answer and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your problem is. Your Python syntax is wrong. Use of Odoo framework is wrong too.

I don't know if using email.template is correct the way you did, but here is the best I can do from the point of view of syntax/framework

```
class stock_minimum(models.Model):
    _name = "rcs.stock_minimum"

    warehouse = fields.Many2one("stock.warehouse")
    product = fields.Many2one("product.product")
    available = fields.Float(compute="_compute_balance", string="Available Quantity")
    percentage = fields.Float(compute="_compute_balance", string="Percentage %")
    quantity = fields.Float(string="Minimum Quantity")

    @api.one
    def _compute_balance(self):
        transactions = self.env['rcs.stock_transaction'].search([('product','=',self.product.id),('warehouse','=',self.warehouse.id)])
        balance = 0.0
        for transaction in transactions:
            if transaction.trans_type == "incoming":
                balance = balance + transaction.quantity
            else:
                balance = balance - transaction.quantity
        self.available = balance
        self.percentage = self.available / self.quantity * 100
        #check from here the additional codes
        if (self.available <= self.quantity):
            template = self.env['email.template'].search([("name","=","minimumstock")])                                                                           
            mail_message = self.env['email.template'].send_mail(template[0].id,self.id)
```

Comment: I did change the code to this no error but still no email is sent

Comment: probably you should configure your smtp. Btw this code should work 99%

Comment: Yeah my smtp shows the -2 error even on test connection im going to try to fix it then i will confirm the codes

Comment: @Alessandro_ruffolo i corrected the smtp but it still doesnt send the email,no errors though